# Consistent newlines in FTP mode for text files?

Tags: windows, linux, ftp

I use Linux for hosting and editing code, but there are others at work that are using Windows. Sometimes they make the files have `\r\n` in them, and it's causing problems with version control.

Should they be using the `ASCII` mode in their FTP manager? Should that force the line endings to be `\n` when uploading from Windows to Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII mode works by converting all line terminators to \r\n in transit, and then having the receiving system convert this sequence to its native line-termination form.

So yes, if the files from the Windows users consistently have \r\n throughout, then uploading them in ASCII mode to a Linux box should result in the received files having \n throughout.

(I'm not entirely sure what would happen if the files have \n in some places and \r\n in others; you might then end up with the received files having extra CRs in some places.)